# wc command to exclude files containing less than X lines

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to run the following code to exclude files with less than 6 lines, however it seems to be excluding files with more lines, and randomly including some with less. The if/else statement is in a loop and $filename has been defined.

```
 if [[ $(wc -l $f) > 6 ]]; then
    echo "$filename"
  else
    echo "skipping $filename"
  fi
```

Comment: ok $filename is defined but what is $f?

Comment: @alicia M , if any of the following answer provided you correct solution , please acknowledge by accepting the answer by ticking right sign beside the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with `wc -l` output, it result file name along with line numbers.

```
if [[ $(wc -l $f|awk '{print $1}') > 6 ]]; then
    echo "$filename"
  else
    echo "skipping $filename"
  fi
```

`wc -l` return the line number with the name of file. so you need to remove the file name before comparing. Example:

```
wc -l ola
7 ola
```

Comment: you should remove one parenthesis: `$(wc -l $f|awk '{print $1}') > 6`

Comment: Or `(( $(wc -l < $f) > 6 ))`.

Comment: From `help test`: "STRING1 > STRING2 True if STRING1 sorts after STRING2 **lexicographically**." So you might want to use `[[ $(wc -l <$f) -gt 6 ]]` or `(( $(wc -l <$f) > 6 ))`

Comment: Thanks the awk function worked, however I had to use the arithmetic brackets as suggested by @alvitis